# İn an Entity-Relationship diagram, do I need both attribute and relatiosnhip?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm preparing an E-R diagram for my school project. I have 2 questions but same type questions.

1. I have `DEPARTMENT` entity and a `BUILDING` entity. A department can be in only one building and in a building, may be several departments. So I have an one-to-many relationship. Should I add an attribute `building_code` to department? If department entity has an attribute called `building_code`, is this incorrect? (building entity has `building_code` attribute and there is a relationship diamond called "includes" between department and building entities already. )
2. I have a `PATIENT` entity and `TEST` entity. A patient can have several tests, but each test belongs to one patient only. So One-to-Many relationship again. I have a relationship named "patient_get" in my E-R diagram and its between patient and test entities of course. So, is test entity needs a "patient_id" attribute? patient_id  attribute is primary key for the PATIENT entity set by the way.

Comment: Under certain circumstances you can do that, but the explanation is rewriting your textbook, and whether you are permitted to do it when you can do it & exactly how depends on the method you are using & how it makes ER or ERis designs & how it maps them to relational or SQL designs. So show your work following your textbook & ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question about where you are 1st stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E-R diagrams the information is represented through entity and relations, not through foreign keys, which are the way in which associations are represented in the Relational Data Model. So the answer is no to both your questions.

Comment: They don't appear to be talking about relationships as FKs, but about cases of ANDing a binary 1:M relation(ship)/association with/into an entity set predicate & correspondingly joining a relationship & an entity table into 1. It can be logically sound, although depends on the method & constraints.